# unbound method set() must be called with StringVar instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Help please,
error: unbound method set() must be called with StringVar instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import * 

interfaz = Frame(height=700,width=400)
interfaz.pack(padx=20,pady=20)

v = StringVar
v.set("")

txt1 = Entry(interfaz,textvariable=v,width=20).place(x=140,y=250)   
interfaz.mainloop()
```

Comment: `StringVar` is a reference to the class. `StringVar()` creates an instance of the class. You're doing the former, but need to do the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use StringVar() instead of StringVar. 
like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

interfaz = Frame(height=700,width=400)
interfaz.pack(padx=20,pady=20)

v = StringVar()
v.set("")

txt1 = Entry(interfaz,textvariable=v,width=20).place(x=140,y=250)
interfaz.mainloop()
```